# Determine the path of the executing Bash script

Tags: bash

In a Windows command script, one can determine the *directory* path of the currently executing script using `%~dp0`. For example:

```
@echo Running from %~dp0
```

What would be the equivalent in a [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) script?

Answer (score 214, accepted):

For the relative path (i.e. the direct equivalent of Windows' `%~dp0`):

```
MY_PATH="$(dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")"
echo "$MY_PATH"
```

For the absolute, normalized path:

```
MY_PATH="$(dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")"            # relative
MY_PATH="$(cd -- "$MY_PATH" && pwd)"    # absolutized and normalized
if [[ -z "$MY_PATH" ]] ; then
  # error; for some reason, the path is not accessible
  # to the script (e.g. permissions re-evaled after suid)
  exit 1  # fail
fi
echo "$MY_PATH"
```

Comment: what is the problem on your mac bash? works just fine over here on Cygwin, Linux, Solaris, etc., and it must also work on mac

Comment: it only gives the relative path though

Comment: $0 gives "-bash" and then dirname argue about "-b" option.

Comment: @Mykola, This is because you are running it directly at the command prompt, not from a script, and because mac is anal about what $0 is at the command prompt (the above works at the command prompt on all other platforms BTW.)

Comment: If you do "exec /bin/bash" you'll then populate $0 with what you want.

Comment: If this is bash specifically I'd use `$()` over `\`\``. The only thing that \` has better is POSIX-compatibility.

Comment: Within bash you can also use `$BASH_SOURCE`.  
From [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in).

Comment: $0 would be OK in most cases, some exceptions are, for instance, when the script you're executing is aliased (through alias in .bash_profile). You should really use $BASH_SOURCE variable, instead of $0.

Comment: Doesn't work for me when I execute a script via a symlink. Is there a variant which will determine the fully-resolved script directory? EDIT: `$(dirname $(readlink $0))` seems to work

Comment: Using `$0` does not work when the script is run using `source script` or `. script`; the name of the script is not available.

Comment: @christopher see @james's or @Dmitri's comment about using `$BASH_SOURCE`

Comment: `%dp0` gives the normalized absolute path.

Comment: This answer is partially incorrect, because if you are in the user folder and your script is in the `Documents` folder, if you call it so `. Documents/test.sh`, the output will be `.`, If you call it so `./Documents/test.sh`, the output will be correct `Documents`, so the exact solution is: `MY_PATH="$(dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")"`

Answer (score 31):

Assuming you type in the full path to the bash script, use `$0` and `dirname`, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$0"
dirname "$0"
```

Example output:

```
$ /a/b/c/myScript.bash
/a/b/c/myScript.bash
/a/b/c
```

If necessary, append the results of the `$PWD` variable to a relative path.

EDIT: Added quotation marks to handle space characters.

Comment: @Rothko, your solution will fail if $0 contains blanks.

Comment: Within bash you can also use `$BASH_SOURCE`.  
From [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in).

Answer (score 11):

Contributed by ***Stephane CHAZELAS*** on c.u.s.
Assuming POSIX shell:

```
prg=$0
if [ ! -e "$prg" ]; then
  case $prg in
    (*/*) exit 1;;
    (*) prg=$(command -v -- "$prg") || exit;;
  esac
fi
dir=$(
  cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "$prg")" && pwd -P
) || exit
prg=$dir/$(basename -- "$prg") || exit 

printf '%s\n' "$prg"
```

Comment: brilliant works for me on Mac OSX the other approaches in this question did not.

Comment: +1 for dealing with script invocation via `$PATH` search; however, the above **is NOT POSIX**. It will only work with `bash`.  Use `which` instead of `command` and backticks instead of `$(...)` is this has to run under other, older shells.

Comment: Hi @vladr, the above code is POSIX! If I understand correctly, what you mean is that the code won't run with the old Bourne shell (/bin/sh on Solaris < 11 for instance), but that has nothing to do with POSIX.

Comment: @DimitreRadoulov sorry yes I meant the lowest common-denominator POSIX, for most portability, i.e. POSIX.1.  Technically yes, any POSIX.2 shell as well as old `ksh` etc., not just `bash`, will run the above, but quite a few people out there are still on Solaris 10 (end-of-support is 2018, quite a few more years to go), and some even run old AIX and HP-UX.

Comment: @vladr, Bourne shell is not POSIX compliant and it predates the POSIX standards. The standardized user command line and scripting interface of POSIX.1 were based on the Korn Shell. As far as I know all commercial Unices offer a POSIX compliant shell (it's /usr/xpg4/bin/sh on Solaris for example).

Answer (score 6):

```
echo Running from $(dirname "$0")
```

Answer (score 3):

Vlad's code is overquoted.  Should be:

```
MY_PATH=`dirname "$0"`
MY_PATH=`( cd "$MY_PATH" && pwd )`
```

Comment: Your second line has an extra double-quote character.

Comment: The overquoting was needed on older Solaris versions, which were still being used at the time of the original post.

Comment: Surely the parentheses are unnecessary even on Solaris?