# How can I make Gitolite post-receive hook to show full path to modified file?

Tags: git, hook, gitolite, git-post-receive

Here is my post-receive hook:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read oldrev newrev ref; do
        git diff --name-only oldrev..newrev
        git --work-tree=/tmp checkout HEAD -- plugin.yml
        echo -e "Test complete maybe..." | tee >(exec logger)
done
```

And here is the output:

[image]

And if I replace oldrev..newrev by oldrev -- newrev, the output is:
[image]

I need to get folder in which this file(plugin.yml) was modified. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this should be $oldrev and $newrev within the loop. See more example at https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-iterate-over-a-variable-range-of-numbers-in-bash/ or https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/

Comment: YES, It shows it :D And the FINAL question: how can I put this path into the variable? Maybe test=${git diff --name-only oldrev..newrev}?

Comment: Yes, except it is test=$(), not ${}. See "command substitution" at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4570/7490

Comment: @VonC I adore you so much! :3 No one else would help me for so long time and tolerate me. 1.000.000 thanks again, you are awesome!!! I don`t know even basics of Linux, shame on me. Will do my best to study it and not to ask stupid questions.. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, each hook can simply check its [execution path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/630387/6309): that will give you the name of the repo.

Second, the [`git diff --name-only`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9478883/6309) I mentioned in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45272956/6309)  will give you the relative path of the file being pushed (including `mod1/2`).

```
git diff --name-only $1..$2
```

since the post-receive hook receives `oldrev`, `newrev` and `ref` on standard input.